# Prettify Symbols extension in VSCode messes with commands

Tags: vscode

I have started to use VSCode for writing and compiling LaTeX files and so far I am liking it a lot for the highly customizable experience. I am using the extension "Prettify Symbols Mode" to replace certain LaTeX commands in the code with their actual counterparts e.g. writing `\alpha` prints as `α` in the editor already which makes the code way more readable.

Now a problem has emerged, which I don't know how to solve properly:

Writing a command like `\multiline` becomes `μltiline` because the `\mu` is printed as a `μ`

The code that "transforms" the symbols looks like the following:

```
{
    "ugly": "\\\\mu",
    "pretty": "μ"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: if that's a regexp match try `\\\\mu\\b` but I'm not sure if it is?

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: ooh good guess:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regexp match so you could use `\\\\mu\\b`  where `\b` is the usual regex symbol for a word boundary (ie it ensures `mu` is not followed by a letter).  (`\`  are doubled due to usual string quoting pain, so the real regexp is `\\mu\b`)